# how to use MediaTek MT7118 WiMAX USB Card with Tp Link Wireless Router?

Tags: wimax

I'm from Bangladesh. The name of my ISP Qubee (Augere Wireless Broadband Bangladesh Limited)
The network the modem uses is Wi-Max(4G). and the Tp Link router (TL MR-3220) I bought also supports 4g.
The name of my country is neither listed on the router nor in the site of Tp Link.
After connecting the modem to the USB port of the router, it shows Unplugged. Also the modem's indicator doesn't light up.

Now my question is, How can I use the modem in the router ?
or is there any way, I can get the bandwidth from the modem in my PC and bypass it to the router ?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question correctly, you want to share your wi-max through your router from your computer. while, if thats it, then you need 3 things

1. a router (preferably wireless)
2. an ethernet cable
3. a program called connectify me

first of of< google and download the software connectify me. pretty straight forward with that. after the software has installed and restarted. connect your wi-max to your pc and make sure your internet is working. 
go to connectify me and use the following setting
under "internet to share" use the wi-max adaptor
under "share over" use the lan adaptor. check your network settings for the name of your adaptor
under "sharing mode" use ethernet
when you have done all this above, click on start hotspot.
it should see and connect your router. and if your router has wireless functions, then you can connect your mobile devices to the router as well to share the internet from the wi-max

hope this helps.